# Flatten laravel nested relationship (parent to descendants) get all childerns

Tags: sql, database, laravel

[image]

**This is my Controller**

```
$categoryIds = Category::select('id')->with('childrenRecursive')->where('id', 1)->get();
 Ad::whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)->get();
```

**This is my model**

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function childs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function Ads() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Ad::class, Category::class, 'parent_id', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

How get all childern categories ides

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with this solution

My Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $parent = Category::with('descendants')->find(1);
    $descendants = $this->traverseTree($parent, collect([1]));
    $ads = Ad::whereIn('category_id',$descendants)->get();
    return response($ads);
}

    protected function traverseTree($subtree, $des)
    {
        $descendants = $des;
        if ($subtree->descendants->count() > 0) {
            foreach ($subtree->descendants as $descendant) {
                $descendants->push($descendant);
                $this->traverseTree($descendant, $descendants);

            }
        }
        return $descendants;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly you need to get ads corresponding to id's of all related records also, for a given category record.

```php
$category = Category::with('childs:id,parent_id')
    ->where('id', 1)
    ->firstOrFail();

$categoryIds = collect([$category->parent_id, $category->id]);

$category->childs->map(fn($child) => $categoryIds->push($child->id));

$ads = Ads::whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds->filter()->all())
    // Can eager load the product(s) if needed
    //->with('products')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with Laravel's Subqueries approach.

```
$parentId = 4;

Ad::whereIn('category_id', function($q) use ($parentId) {
   $q->select('id')
     ->from('categories')
     ->where('parent_id', $parentId);
});
```

If you want to add the parent model, you can chain `with()`:

```
Ads::whereIn('category_id', function($q) use ($parentId) {
   $q->select('id')
     ->from('categories')
     ->where('parent_id', $parentId);
})
  ->with('category.parent')
  ->get();
```

Your code chunks are not clear so you may need to tweak my code example.

Comment: i can get all product inherit category id
this query just get product with parent id